# Does @discardableResult actually lead to compiler optimizations?

Tags: swift, function, optimization, compilation, compiler-optimization

I have an assignment operation that I want to also return the new value my object is assigned, but only optionally. So of course I would add the `@discardableResult` attribute. However, does this actually tell the compiler to ignore the return statement inside my function definition if it is not actually being passed anywhere? What optimization does this attribute actually do? All the documentation says is that it "suppresses the warning," although I only want to use it if it can be easily optimized.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: No, this is not the intent of `@discardableResult` attribute. It doesn't ignore return statement: the result from such function can still be used, but is optional. So it simply silences the warning when the result is not used.

Comment: @KirilS. That's unfortunate. Does that mean it would not be efficient to use it and ignore return values, because there would be return values generated but the result would go unused?

Comment: technically - yes, but in most cases it's a very small inefficiency (unless your function returns something giant). Because typically the reason you have function with `@discardableResult` is because it generally does something useful, you just don't care about result it returns.

Comment: @KirilS. I am making an assignment operator (like `+=`), but I also want to be able to use the result of it (e.g. `a = b += c`). Would this be an appropriate time to use `@discardableResult`?

Comment: That's exactly the right case to use it, yes